# Maintaining windows state in an SAP application

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am designing an SAP application.The first window opens in one machine and when i click on certain button on first screen window, it should open second window on second screen. 
The question is - I am not able to maintain the session across the 2 windows i.e. let say i use some filters on first windows, so these filters should be applied to the contents of second window too.
P.S. It is server side application and javascript is being used.

Anyone help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it, it depends a little on what you want exactly.
It is also not really clear what backend you have (I deduce that you use UI5 on the front end).

On the top of my head, I can think of the following:

- Communicate between windows using JS references. You can get the parent window with [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) and you can get a reference to the child window when you use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Then you can simply call (global) functions to do this communication. The main issue that I see is that when you have more than just two windows, this will become cumbersome.
- Use [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to store the state of the filtering and so on. You can [attach listeners to the cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged) and update the state of your filtering based on the content of the cookie (i.e. one window "publishes" to the cookie and the other listeners "consume" the changes).
- The same thing as above, but with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). This would be a more "modern" solution.
- Do some server-side storage and use a *pull* mechanism (HTTP polling, Websockets or HTTP/2 SSE).